# Sed inside a while read loop

Tags: sed, while-loop

I have been reading a lot of questions and answers about using sed within a while loop. I think I have the command down correctly, but I seem to get no output once I put all of the pieces together. Can someone tell me what I am missing?

I have an input file with 700 variables, one on each line. I need to use each of these 700 variables within a sed command. I run the following command to verify variables are outputting correctly:

> cat Input_File.txt | while read var; do echo $var; done

I then try to add in the sed command as follows:

> cat Input_File.txt | while read var; do sed -n "/$var/,+10p" Multi-BLAST_5814.txt >> Multi_BLAST_Subset; done

This command leaves me without an error, but a blinking cursor as if this is an infinite loop. It should use each of the 700 variables, find the corresponding line in Multi_BLAST_5814.txt and output the search variable line and the 10 lines after the search term into a new file, appending each as it goes. I can execute the sed command alone with a manually set single value variable successfully and I can execute the while loop successfully using the input file. Anyone have a thought as to why this is not working?

User, that is exactly what I have done to this point.

I have a large text file (128 MB) with BLAST output. I need to search through this for a subset of results for 769 samples (Out of the 5814 samples that are in the file).

I have created a .txt file with those 769 sample names.

To test grep and sed, I manually assigned a variable with one of the 769 samples names I need to search and can get the results I need as follows:

```
$ Otu="S41_Folmer_Otu96;size=12;"
$ grep $Otu -A 10 Multi_BLAST_5814.txt
            OR
```

$ sed -n "/$Otu/,+10p" Multi_BLAST_5814.txt

The OUTPUT is exactly what I want as follows:

```
    Query= S41_Folmer_Otu96;size=12;
    Length=101

    Sequences producing significant alignments:       Score(Bits)  E Value

    gi|58397553|gb|AY830431.1|  Scopelocheirus schellenbergi clone...   180    1E-41
    gi|306447543|gb|HQ018876.1|  Liposcelis paeta isolate CZ cytoc...   174    6E-40
    gi|306447533|gb|HQ018871.1|  Liposcelis decolor isolate CQ cyt...   104    9E-19
    gi|1043259532|gb|KX130860.1|  Batocera rufomaculata isolate Br...   99    4E-17
    gi|987210821|gb|KR141076.1|  Psocoptera sp. BOLD:ACO1391 vouch...   81    1E-11
```

To Test to make sure the input file contains the correct variables I run the following:

```
$ Cat Input_File.txt
$ while read Otu; do echo $Otu; done <Input_File.txt

    S41_Folmer_Otu96;size=12;
    S78_Folmer_Otu15;size=538;
    S73_Leray_Otu52;size=6;
    S66_Leray_Otu93;size=6;
    S10_Folmer_Otu10;size=1612;
    ... All 769 variables
```

Again, this is exactly what I expect and is correct.

But, When I do either of the following commands, nothing is printed to the screen (if I leave off the write file/append action) or to the file I need to create.

> $ cat Input_File.txt | while read Otu; do grep "$Otu" -A 10 Multi_BLAST_5814.txt >> Multi_BLAST_Subset.txt; done
>
> $ cat Input_File.txt | while read Otu; do sed -n "/$Otu/,+10p" Multi_BLAST_5814.txt >> Multi_BLAST_Subset.txt; done

Sed hangs and never closes, leaving me at a blinking cursor. Grep finishes but also gives no output. I am at a loss as to why this is not working. Everything works inidividually, so I may be left with manually searching all 769 samples copy/paste.

Comment: The only important Q&A about `questions and answers about using sed within a while loop` are Q) Should I used sed within a while loop to manipulate text? A) No. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice). [editt] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output and we can help you do whatever it is you're trying to do the right way.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to GNU `grep` no need for a `sed` command, `grep "$var" -A 10` will do the same thing and won't break if `$var` contains the delimiter used in your `sed` command.

From `man grep` :

> ```
>    -A NUM, --after-context=NUM
>           Print  NUM  lines  of  trailing  context  after  matching lines.
>           Places  a  line  containing  a  group  separator  (--)   between
>           contiguous  groups  of  matches.  With the -o or --only-matching
>           option, this has no effect and a warning is given.
> ```

Comment: grep command does not work either... At least with grep, the command finishes, but there is nothing in the output file

Comment: @BrettOlds : try `grep -Ff your700VarList.txt -A 10 bigFile > smallerFile` . `man grep` for what is happening, or search here for similar Qs. If your data doesn't trip you up, you can do this with one call to grep. not 700. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter : That was closer, I did end up with the last search item, but only the one. I tried to change it up to append with the following command: grep -Ff your700VarList.txt -A 10 bigFile >> smallerFile. But this too only returns a single entry

Comment: @BrettOlds check your input file's linefeeds. If they are Window's `\r\n` that might explain your problem as both `grep -Ff` and `read` will treat `\r`s as standard characters, and you would end up searching for `yourVar\r` in your bigger file. Bit of a wild guess, but that would explain the different behaviour for the last var if it isn't followed by a linefeed

Comment: @BrettOlds : Yes, agree about `\r\n` line endings. Look for them with `cat -vet your700VarList.txt`. If you see `^M$` at the end of lines, then use `dos2unix your700*`. You'll probably also need to check your `bigFile` as well. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether you have already attempted it but try breaking the problem into smaller chunks. Simple example below :

```
$ cat Input_File.txt 
one
two
three
$

$ cat file.txt 
This is line one
This is line two
This is line three
This is another four
This is another five
This is another six
This is another seven
$

$ cat Input_File.txt | while read var ; do echo $var ; sed -n "/$var/,+1p" file.txt ; done
one
This is line one
This is line two
two
This is line two
This is line three
three
This is line three
This is another four
$
```